# Python Popen difficulties: File not found

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to use python to run a program.

```
from subprocess import Popen 
sa_proc = Popen(['C:\\sa\\sa.exe','--?'])
```

Running this small snippit gives the error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The program exists and I have copy and pasted directly from explorer the absolute path to the exe. I have tried other things and have found that if I put the EXE in the source folder with the python script and use './sa.exe' then it works. The only thing I can think of is that I'm running the python script (and python) from a separate partition (F:).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: An unrelated note: you can use raw strings to avoid the need to escape backslashes, ie. r'C:\sa\sa.exe'

Comment: Can you execute this file _in the same way_ using command prompt?

Comment: I don't think it's not the partition issue.  I put an exe on another drive and ran it successfully with Popen.

Comment: Pythong ain't no language I ever heard of :)

Comment: To the above: Yes the exe runs from command prompt, and I realized my typo after the fact, thanks to the mod/person that corrected that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen) say, "On Windows: the Popen class uses CreateProcess() to execute the child program, which operates on strings. If args is a sequence, it will be converted to a string using the list2cmdline() method.".  Maybe that method is messing things up, so why not try the simpler approach of:

```
sa_proc = Popen('C:\\sa\\sa.exe --?')
```

If this still fails, then: what's `os.environ['COMSPEC']` just before you try this?  What happens if you add `, shell=True` to `Popen`'s arguments?

**Edit**: turns out apparently to be a case of simple mis-spellling, as 'sa' was actually the program spelled SpamAssassin -- double s twice -- and what the OP was writing was spamassasin -- one double s but a single one the second time.

Comment: Converting it back to just a regular string as you suggested didn't work. os.environ['COMSPEC'] = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe and Popen('C:\\spamassasin\\spamassasin.exe --?', shell=True) Outputs: 'C:\spamassasin\spamassasin.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: It's spelled SpamAssassin -- double s twice -- and what you're writing is spamassasin -- one double s but a single one the second time. Editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: It appears to have been a typo issue after all, which is weird since I copy/pasted directory and filename prior to this, and it still hadn't worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not have permission to execute C:\sa\sa.exe.  Have you tried running the program manually?

Comment: Program runs when manually executed. This user account has admin rights and was the same user that created the exe I am attempting to run.